# IgnoreRoute not working for PIE.htc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css3pie, ignoreroute

I've been search for a long time and just can't seem to find my mistake. For my MVC 3 website, I need buttons with rounded edges, so in the IE stylesheet I register the PIE.htc. Now the problem is that when a button is clicked, the PIE.htc is offered to the user as a download when redirecting the UrlReferr View. I implemented the PIE as described here: [css3pie in MVC, where to place the pie.htc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870870/css3pie-in-mvc-where-to-place-the-pie-htc-file)

The following routes should be ignored:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("PIE.htc");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Resource and favicon work, but the PIE.htc seems to be ignored. Any ideas why?